# Php storm doesn't recognize JavaScript

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I was working on the PHPStorm IDE, all was perfect, but I just don't know what has happened now it's not recognizing Javascript, .js files are appearing like dtd files.

Has anybody had this kind of issue?

[here's the issue  in more detail](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22908/php-storm-doesnt-recognize-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see `Settings` | `File Types`. Verify that your files are associated with the **JavaScript** file type. Also ensure that JavaScript plug-in is enabled in `Settings` | `Plugins`.

Comment: Thanks it helped, added ".js" extension to the javascript file types