# Javascript Files Not Being Recognised Webstorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

All of a sudden webstorm doesn't recognise Javascript for me.

If I add a file like this :

[image]

All I see in my IDE afterwards is this :

[image]

If I refresh, restart Webstorm, it still does not recognise the file! Webstorm has become unusable!

Comment: Is this webstorm 10?

Comment: Oh. 10 works ok for me :-)

Comment: Couldn't it be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330571/php-storm-doesnt-recognize-javascript

Comment: A bit of off topic: You do not need to provide extension when creating file using specialized "new file" dialog (like on your screenshot) -- it only required if you are using generic "new file" where full file name is required (which allows you to create files like "README" or ".htaccess")

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872024/webstorm-not-recognising-javascript-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webstorm not recognising Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872024/webstorm-not-recognising-javascript-file)

Answer (score 3):

If @Bruno's link doesn't help, please try to right click the file and select "mark as plain text". Once done, right click it again and select "mark as javascript" - works for me in phpStorm

Comment: the problem seems to have suddenly disappeared, but i will try your tip if it happens again. Thanx